# Render giving me nothing but a rough background

Tags: rendering

I'm making a little picture 
[image]

And when I click (shift-Z) it gives me this
[image]
I have no idea what caused this if anyone has an idea how to fix this, that would be very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried setting *size* in **depth of field** to 0?

Comment: Just checking.. Lights?

Comment: It was the size of the depth of field I had it at 0.05 and it gave me the second image but when I put it to 0 it fixed it so thank you Leander